# How to rotate an Image in Matlab 90 degrees

Tags: matlab

I have an image that I'd like to rotate by 90 degrees right, how can I do it without using any toolbox.

I've written a function that puts a picture on a sub-picture after user gives 4 points. I believe there has to be an easier way.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: just use `imrotate`!

Comment: I can't use functions from the "Image Processing Toolbox".

Comment: [`rot90`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html) ?

Comment: The duplicate appears a bit overkill to me, as this question is only on 90 degrees, so `rot90` or `permute` do the job well enough, and there's no need for that complicated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing rot90 rotates the image to the left try this.

1. Flip the image
2. Rotate it left
3. Flip it back.

The image will then be rotated right.  Whether it is flipped left-right using fliplr or up-down using flipud does not matter.

-or-

Use rot90 3 times.

The following is a slight modification of the MATLAB example

```
load mandrill
figure('color','k')
image(fliplr(rot90(fliplr(X))))
colormap(map) 
axis off          % Remove axis ticks and numbers
axis image
```

Comment: You can just perform `rot90(I,3)` instead of using it 3 times.

Comment: @NKN or `rot90(I,-1)`.